# Ubuntu: Monitor hardware RAID and notify upon failure?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, raid1, 3ware

I am using the [3ware 9650SE-2LP Raid controller](http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/internal_raid/sata/3ware_sata_raid_controllers/9650se-2lp/index.html) for a 2-drive RAID 1 setup in some new Ubuntu 10.04 x64 servers.

Is there a way for the server to send me a notification when one of the drives fails?  I would prefer an e-mail notification if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3ware provides 3dm2 monitoring / management program. just look onm their webpage, there is a binary version of it for linux, and it even works fine [under debian at least].

thing is - i never trusted those fancy tools... so i do as follows. so i use own scripts based on tw_cli - also downloadable from 3ware website.

once per week i run patrol read:

```
./tw_cli /c0/u0 start verify
```

and all the time, every 15 minutes i dump current state of raid:

```
./tw_cli /c0 show > current.txt
```

i use very simple nagios plugin to check if current status is identical to expected [ i just compare content of a file to well known status dump that was taken at the beginning ].

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ `diff current.txt expected.txt|wc -l` -ne 0 ] ; then
        echo "CRITICAL - current state of raid does not match expected pattern "
        exit 2
fi

if [ `find . -name current.txt -mmin -16|wc -l` -ne 1 ] ; then
        echo "CRITICAL - state file is old "
        exit 2
fi
echo "OK"
exit 0
```

you would probably put mailing instead of exit 2... or even more probably use 3dm2.

Comment: That Exit 2/Exit 0 stuff is for nagios compatibility.  You can use this script as a nagios plugin, and let nagios centrally handle the alerting/escalation/uptime computation.

Comment: @Jason - yes.. i know it very well - i use it with nagios...

Comment: Ah... I should have looked at the included CD more carefully.  Thanks.